# Issue withMedia Query

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm trying to apply media queries to my website, but it doesn't work at all. I cannot add style rules inside of media queries. I can add styles only if I do not use braces like:

```
"@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
    width: 100%;
}"
```

But once I use braces like below, class names become red colored letters and errors.

```
"@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
    ul.menus{
        width: 100%;
    }
}"
```

Below is the layout file that I created first. I would like to add media queries to change this layout differently on mobile devices. I checked my view port tag, and everything was fine. I tried  to connect CSS file with media query to html, but it still didn't work.

```
"@charset "utf-8";

/*
   Homepage layout
*/
body{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 5% 30% 30% 30% 5%;
    grid-template-rows: 30px 260px 430px 30px;
}

header{
    grid-column:  2/5;
    grid-row: 1/2;
}
img#header{
    grid-column: 2/5;
    grid-row: 2/3;
}
aside.profile{
    grid-column: 2/3;
    grid-row: 3/4;
}
article{
    grid-column: 3/4;
    grid-row: 3/4;    
}
aside.schedule{
    grid-column: 4/5;
    grid-row: 3/4;
}
footer{
    grid-column:  2/5;
    grid-row: 4/5;
}"
```

Comment: Please post a [mre] demonstrating your problem.

Comment: checkout the syntax and sample example codes here. It may help to solve your problem https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp